# XOR giving unexpected output in JAVA

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, xor, bitwise-xor

I am trying to implement finite fields in JAVA, for which I need to XOR two binary numbers.
Here is my code:

```
            String lastdigits="1000110";
            int overflow=11;
            int lastdigitsint=Integer.parseInt(lastdigits);
            int result=(int) lastdigitsint^overflow;
```

The value of the variable 'overflow' is `11`. 
When I am XORing lastdigitsint with overflow (=11), the output should be 1000101. However, the code is outputting 1095.

Can someone explain why this is happening? Thank you.

Comment: You could simplify this example a good bit, and provide hard-coded values

Comment: Hi. I am new to StackOverflow, so I'm still learning the rules here. Thank you for the guidance!

Comment: Also, I have edited my code to bare minimum. Yes, I debugged it in IntelliJ, and I'm sure the correct values are being stored in the variable 'lastdigits' and 'overflow'.

Comment: I ran the code and got `1000101`. Isn't that what you expected?

Comment: You are not using 2-based numbers but decimal ones, `Integer.parseInt(lastdigits)` does not return what you think. If you are using Java 7, then instead of `int lastdigitsint=Integer.parseInt("1000110");` you can just use `int lastdigitsint=0b1000110;` which is 2-based. Quite probably happens the same with your variable `overflow`

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong from the beginning

```
    String lastdigits="1000110";
    int lastdigitsint=Integer.parseInt(lastdigits);
```

last digit value will be 1000110 - thats **ten millions houndred and ten**
so the binary representation is far different from what you expected.
What you want to do is simply:

```
int lastdigitsint=0b1000110;
```

this is proper binary integer.

So:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String lastdigits = "1000110";
    int overflow = 0b11;
    int lastdigitsint = Integer.parseInt(lastdigits);
    int result = lastdigitsint ^ overflow;

    System.out.println("Dec:" + lastdigitsint);
    System.out.println("Dec:" + overflow);
    System.out.println("Dec:" + result);
    System.out.println("Bin" + Integer.toBinaryString(lastdigitsint));
    System.out.println("Bin" + Integer.toBinaryString(overflow));
    System.out.println("Bin" + Integer.toBinaryString(result));

    System.out.println("And now the proper way:");
    lastdigitsint = 0b1000110;
    result = lastdigitsint ^ overflow;

    System.out.println("Dec:" + lastdigitsint);
    System.out.println("Dec:" + overflow);
    System.out.println("Dec:" + result);
    System.out.println("Bin" + Integer.toBinaryString(lastdigitsint));
    System.out.println("Bin" + Integer.toBinaryString(overflow));
    System.out.println("Bin" + Integer.toBinaryString(result));
}
```

Result:

```
Dec:1000110
Dec:3
Dec:1000109
Bin:11110100001010101110
Bin:11
Bin:11110100001010101101
And now the proper way:
Dec:70
Dec:3
Dec:69
Bin:1000110
Bin:11
Bin:1000101
```

Seams legit to me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you also please explain why the binary representation would be different for this number? (Since this code is working for other binary numbers I am inputting, even large ones).

Comment: Also, I cannot hardcode the value of lastdigitsint. This is just a part of the code of my entire program, and the String lastdigits is being generated by a for loop. Is there any other method to give the correct output?

Comment: The thing is, you are XORing not with 11b (3dec) but with 11dec (1011bin)

Answer (score 1):

You are not XORing the numbers you think you are XORing.

You are XORing one million one hundred and ten with eleven

The XOR is performed on the bits of the binary representation of those two numbers, so you are XORing the binary numbers `11110100001010101110` and `1011`, which results in `11110100001010100101`. The interesting part is that the decimal representation of that number is `1000101`, which is exactly the binary representation of the result you would get if you XORed the binary numbers `1000110` and `11`.

```
Decimal     Binary

1000110  == 11110100001010101110
                               ^
     11  == 00000000000000001011
            --------------------
1000101  == 11110100001010100101
```

If you want to XOR the binary numbers `1000110` and `11`, you should write :

```
        String lastdigits="1000110";
        int overflow=3; // 11 in binary is 3 in decimal
        int lastdigitsint=Integer.parseInt(lastdigits,2);
        int result=(int) lastdigitsint^overflow;
```

That would give you the decimal number `69` (whose binary representation is `1000101`).